# How to use Create-React-App in non react app

Tags: reactjs

I have created an app using create-react-app. I want to build it so I can add it to a non-React webpage. How do I bundle it up so I can just add the script at the bottom of an HTML page and the app will show?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute

Comment: If I get your question correctly, [Micro Front-end](https://micro-frontends.org/) concept will help